# Binary Search Tree – Number of comparisons when element is not found

Tags: binary-search-trees

I am confused regarding Binary Search Trees (BST) when an element does not exist in the tree.

For example, to search for element "6", would it take 5 comparisons to search for this element?

My understanding is:

1. Compare root (Not found - move left)
2. Compare left node (Not found - move left)
3. Compare left node (Not found - move right)
4. Compare right node (Not found, move right)
5. No right node (6 does not exist)

Is my understanding correct? Would it take 5 comparisons to attempt to search for 6 in this BST?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: The first 4 are real comparisons. Whether and how the last one counts is debatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 4 comparisons: the element 6 is compared to the elements 9,7,4,5.